# Extract numbers from an AlphaNumeric string

Tags: strings, vb.net

I have an alphanumeric string like `sdff45hg589>@#DF456&<jk778P&&FHJ75`, of which I want to extract only the numbers, without using regex or any other functions.

```
Dim input As String = "sdff45hg589>@#DF456&<jk778P&&FHJ75"
Dim output As String = New String((From c As Char In input Select c Where Char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray())
MsgBox(output) 'Display the output
```

The message box will display `4558945677875`.

For extracting letters from the same string, I use the following:

```
 Dim input As String =  "sdff45hg589>@#DF456&<jk778P&&FHJ75"
 Dim output As String = New String((From c As Char In input Select c Where Char.IsLetter(c)).ToArray())
 MsgBox (output)
```

Is this a better way to extract both?

Comment: This appears to be copied from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24650229/1305253

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to extract both at the same time (I don't know if it is a requirement, it isn't clear in the question) you should iterate once through each character to place them in different lists.

```
  Dim input As String = "sdff45hg589>@#DF456&<jk778P&&FHJ75"
  Dim characters As List(Of Char) = New List(Of Char)()
  Dim numbers As List(Of Char) = New List(Of Char)()
  For Each c As Char In input
     If (Char.IsNumber(c)) Then
        numbers.Add(c)
     ElseIf (Char.IsLetter(c)) Then
        characters.Add(c)
     End If
  Next

'Do whatever you have to do here
```

**Edit**

As pointed out @mjolka, since the goal of the user is to show the splitted numbers and letters, a `StringBuilder` would be more appropriate. Here is my updated answer :

```
  Dim input As String = "sdff45hg589>@#DF456&<jk778P&&FHJ75"
  Dim characters As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
  Dim numbers As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
  For Each c As Char In input
     If (Char.IsNumber(c)) Then
        numbers.Append(c)
     ElseIf (Char.IsLetter(c)) Then
        characters.Append(c)
     End If
  Next

'Do whatever you have to do here
```

Comment: I think a `StringBuilder` would be better than a `List(Of Char)`. It makes the intention clearer and you can just call `numbers.ToString()`.

Comment: That is totally true, I'll update my answer

Answer (score 2):

you can do this with a very simple regex replace.

```
Dim match = Regex.Replace("sdff45hg589>@#DF456&<jk778P&&FHJ75", "\D", "")
```

non-digits is "\D", and then replace it with empty string.

I ran for above data it works fine.

Comment: But how to extract letters using this?

Comment: use \d to remove digit.